# Exporting Excel sheet to pdf

Tags: excel, pdf, export

I'm currently working on an Excel Makro for work and one of the command Buttons is supposed to copy the Inputs from a UserForm to a sheet of my workbook and Export this sheet to pdf. The Macro works fine (since I found most of it on the Internet) but it is supposed to stop, once the user hits the "cancel" button on the "file save as" window.

My Problem is, that the macro still saves the sheet and calls the pdf "False.pdf". Can anyone help me to figure out, what I should change for it to run properly?

The Code I use is:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim wsA As Worksheet
    Dim wbA As Workbook
    Dim strTime As String
    Dim strName As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strPathFile As String
    Dim myFile As Variant
    On Error GoTo errHandler

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Export").Range("B2").Value = Label14.Caption
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Export").Range("B4").Value = Label12.Caption
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Export").Range("K4").Value = Paketdruck.Value
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Export").Range("H2").Value = Label16.Caption
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Export").Range("J2").Value = Label18.Caption
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Export").Range("G4").Value = Label22.Caption
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Export").Range("B17").Value = Label37.Caption
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Export").Range("B19").Value = Label38.Caption
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Export").Range("B21").Value = Label39.Caption
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Export").Range("C17").Value = Label42.Caption
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Export").Range("C19").Value = Label43.Caption
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Export").Range("C21").Value = Label44.Caption
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Export").Range("E17").Value = Label46.Caption
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Export").Range("E19").Value = Label47.Caption
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Export").Range("E21").Value = Label48.Caption
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Export").Range("G17").Value = Label50.Caption
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Export").Range("G19").Value = Label51.Caption
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Export").Range("G21").Value = Label52.Caption
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Export").CheckBox1.Value = Me.CheckBox1.Value
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Export").CheckBox2.Value = Me.CheckBox2.Value
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Export").CheckBox3.Value = Me.CheckBox3.Value
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Export").CheckBox4.Value = Me.CheckBox4.Value
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Export").CheckBox5.Value = Me.CheckBox5.Value

    Set wbA = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsA = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Export")
    strTime = Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd")

    'get active workbook folder, if saved
    strPath = wbA.Path
    If strPath = "" Then
        strPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
    End If
    strPath = strPath & "\"

    'create default name for savng file
    strName = wsA.Name
    strFile = strName & "_" & strTime & ".pdf"
    strPathFile = strPath & strFile

    'user can enter name and
    ' select folder for file
    myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
        (InitialFileName:=strPathFile, _
            FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
            Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")

    'export to PDF if a folder was selected
    If myFile <> "False" Then
        wsA.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=myFile, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
    'confirmation message with file info
    MsgBox "PDF file has been created: " _
      & vbCrLf _
      & myFile
    End If

    exitHandler:
        Exit Sub
    errHandler:
        MsgBox "Could not create PDF file"
        Resume exitHandler
End Sub
```

Thanks for the help :)

**Edit** I figured out the issue.
I had to change the result for the "myFile" variable, since I'm using a German Excel license I had to check

```
 If myFile <> "Falsch" Then
 Code
 End If
```

Thanks for the help @SolarMike

Comment: Where do you trap the pressing of "cancel" and redirect to the end?

Comment: In my opinion when pressing cancel the result of "myFile" should be "myFile = False" and the Sub should just end

Comment: Given you say "False.pdf" is the result, then it can't be working like that... Why not put an if() that checks for false and calls the error handler **before** the export bit...

Comment: Thanks for the Help @SolarMike. I figured out the issue. Since I'm living in Germany I'm using a German Excel license. Therefor I had to check
    If myFile <> "Falsch" Then
    Code
    End If